# No function call - onclick doesn't work react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components. The first of them looks like this

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      change: false
    };

    this.handleSwitch = this.handleSwitch.bind(this);
  }

  handleSwitch = () => {
    const { change } = this.state;
    this.setState({ change: !change })
    console.log(this.state.change)
  }

  render() {
    const { change } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <UserProfilPanel handleSwitch={this.handleSwitch}/>
        {
          change ? <UserProfilGallery /> : <UserProfilContent />
        }
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

To the `UserProfile Panel` component, it passes the function which is to be responsible for changing the state.

```
const UserProfil = (handleSwitch) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => handleSwitch}>
          gallery
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => handleSwitch}>
          info
        </button>
      </div>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

When I press some buttons, nothing happens. The console also does not appear an error.

How to fix this problem? I want to change content after clicking the button

Comment: You're not calling `handleSwitch` in your `onClick` handlers, you're just returning the function. `{() => handleSwitch()}` or `{handleSwitch}` is what you need.

Comment: It should beonClick={() => handleSwitch()} and remove this.handleSwitch = this.handleSwitch.bind(this);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First argument in `UserProfil()` is `props`. To destructure only a specific property of the `props` object you need to do:

```
const UserProfil = ({handleSwitch}) => {...
```

Then inside your onClick anonymous function you need to call `handleSwitch()`

```
<button onClick={() => handleSwitch()}>
                           //      ^^  call function
```